# How to separate columns when converting .txt file to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My .txt file looks like this

[Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOm5v.png)

This is my code

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Chilled Water Data/Sec_CW_BTUs.txt")

df.to_csv("Chilled Water Data/NEWSec_CW_BTUs.csv"

df.to_csv("Chilled Water Data/NEWSec_CW_BTUs.csv")
```

I am unsure how I can seperate/create colums when converting (also this file is to large to convert in excel).

Comment: please post a sample of your .txt file instead of an image so we can copy and paste it. you do not need to post the entire thing, a few rows will suffice

Answer (score 0):

Funny, but you need to look at something that my nickname suggests, but widely referred to as *sep*. Specifically, set a separator to what you believe separates the columns.

```
df = pd.read_csv("Chilled Water Data/Sec_CW_BTUs.txt", sep=" ")
```